# dotenv-webpack and terser: error from Terser Invalid assignment

Tags: webpack, dotenv, terser, electron-react-boilerplate

I'm working on an electron application. I've added the `dotenv-webpack` plugin in webpack config, but when I try to build it, I receive an error from Terser. Furthermore, if I comment on the TerserPlugin config, the error still appears.

> Error from Terser Invalid assignment.

```js
import TerserPlugin from 'terser-webpack-plugin';
import Dotenv from 'dotenv-webpack';

export default {
  // ...
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        parallel: true,
      }),
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    // ...
    new Dotenv({
      path: path.join(__dirname, '../../.env'), // The path is correct
      systemvars: true,
    }),
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It caused due to `debug` package.
`node.js` file have follow code:

```js
function save(namespaces) {
    if (namespaces) {
        process.env.DEBUG = namespaces;
    } else {
        // If you set a process.env field to null or undefined, it gets cast to the
        // string 'null' or 'undefined'. Just delete instead.
        delete process.env.DEBUG;
    }
}
```

Which replaced by follow lines, by Dotenv plugin:

```js
function save(namespaces) {
    if (namespaces) {
       "true" = namespaces;
    }  else {
        // If you set a process.env field to null or undefined, it gets cast to the
        // string 'null' or 'undefined'. Just delete instead.
        delete "true;
    }
```